# What is the piano song in the very first beginning of Tokyo Ghoul:re season 2 episode 1?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

What is the piano cover of the 1st episode of *Tokyo ghoul:re* season 2's introduction of in the first 8-second of it?

Answer (score 1):

Name of the song is:
[Believe Again (Piano Version)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID7CUaKyrZI)

Artist:  Yutaka Yamada
Album: Tokyo Ghoul:re OST

Friendly Suggestion:

> Same song but little more Epic!
>  Played with Symphonic Orchestra
>  [Believe Again - (Symphonic Suites)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEKmAp3b_zo)

Answer (score -1):

The soundtrack is called "Tokyo Ghoul :re" I'm pretty sure. Heres a link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTEB3KmuNR8&index=3&list=PLB6qn5wggeAoOI4hpDoRAvN2DwfL-kEjV
Hope it helped!

Comment: Looks like the YouTube link is dead, and I didn't find a song titled "Tokyo Ghoul: re" (or did you mean the album name?). As of current, this answer lacks any useful info to answer the question...